# React Native linking libraries search bar

Tags: react-native

I am trying to use the component search-bar
https://github.com/umhan35/react-native-search-bar

I have followed the instructions and installed it correctly what I am confused about is how to use it as everything I am trying is throwing errors.

To test it I am using it on a program called testingReact which is just the starting react program.

I added the searchBar so the imports look like this.

'use strict';
import React, {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  SearchBar
} from 'react-native';

Now if I run it still does not throw an error

Now I add the following code (taken straight from the example

```
    <View> 
      <SearchBar
        placeholder='Search'
        textFieldBackgroundColor='blue'
        />
    </View>
```

When I run I get the following error "Element type is invalid : expected string(for built in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of 'testingReact'.

Answer (score 0):

[https://github.com/umhan35/react-native-search-bar Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37Ekn.png)

SearchBar is custom component. You can import like this.

```
ES5:
var SearchBar = require('react-native-search-bar');
```

Or

```
ES6:
import SearchBar from 'react-native-search-bar';
```